# Check outlook recipents for group and prompt if missing

Tags: vba, outlook

Trying to set up so that VBA checks both To and CC field for a contact group that contains a number of at least 3 digits and some other characters - the other characters are not important to check for but just saying that they are present. The general form of a group I am hoping to search for would be something like "0239-Customer-Location-Description".

There are a lot of groups and they change frequently as workflow dictates so I was hoping to search for numerical wildcards and count occurrences. If occurrence is = 0, then a MsgPrompt should pop up to remind/check with user to see if they really want to send - after send button has been pressed.

See below for my attempt. Please go easy on me. This is placed in active session w/item send selected.

```vb
Private Sub myOlApp_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)


Dim prompt As String
prompt = "Has your group added? Select Yes to send anyway"

Dim Recipients As Outlook.Recipients
Dim Recip As Outlook.Recipient
Dim Find As String

Dim GroupCount As Long


Find = "*###*"

Set Recipients = Item.Recipients
  For Each Recip In Recipients
      If InStr(1, Recip.Address, Find, vbTextCompare) Then GroupCount = GroupCount + 1 Else: GroupCount = GroupCount
     Exit For
     Next

 'check to see if count is working   
If MsgBox(GroupCount, vbOKOnly, "Group Count") = vbOK Then
    Cancel = True
    


    If GroupCount = 0 Then

         If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "CC Field") = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
    
        
        End If
    End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

`Like` allow wildcards.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim prompt As String
prompt = "Has your group been added? Select Yes to send anyway."

Dim Recipients As Recipients
Dim Recip As Recipient
Dim Find As String

Dim GroupCount As Long

'Find = "*###*"
Find = "*###-*"

Set Recipients = Item.Recipients
For Each Recip In Recipients
    Debug.Print "Recip.Name: " & Recip.Name
        
    'If InStr(1, Recip.Name, Find, vbTextCompare) Then
    If Recip.Name Like Find Then
        GroupCount = GroupCount + 1
            
        ' At least one applicable group found
        'Exit For
            
    Else
        GroupCount = GroupCount
            
    End If
Next

'check to see if count is working
Debug.Print "Group Count: " & GroupCount
'If MsgBox(GroupCount, vbOKOnly, "Group Count") = vbOK Then
    If GroupCount = 0 Then
        If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton2, "No group found.") = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
'End If

End Sub
```